# Using Polly in oppose to Task.TimeoutAfter

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, timeout, polly

How do I use Polly in oppose to `TimeoutAfter`?

I want to use Polly in the following code instead of `TimeoutAfter`:

```cs
public async Task StartAsync()
{
    await _webSocket.ConnectAsync(_uri, CancellationToken.None).TimeoutAfter(OpenTimeoutMs).ConfigureAwait(false);

    ...

    await _webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", CancellationToken.None).TimeoutAfter(CloseTimeoutMs);
}

public static async Task TimeoutAfter(this Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    try
    {
        await task.WaitAsync(timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        throw new TimeoutException($"Task timed out after {timeout}");
    }
}
```

### My thoughts (not sure if I'm correct)

In order Polly to handle things, I need to pass a `CancellationToken` to `StartAsync` and replace `CancellationToken.None` with it.

This is what I think, I don't know if it's correct or not. That's why I ask the question.

```cs
var timeoutPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<TimeoutException>()
    .TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMs), TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic,
        (context, timeSpan, task, ex) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task timed out after {timeSpan.TotalSeconds} seconds");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) =>
{
    await client.StartAsync(ct);
}, CancellationToken.None);

// changed the method to accept CancellationToken
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    await _webSocket.ConnectAsync(_uri, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

    ...

    await _webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Well, in this case you have a "global" timeout for the whole StartAsync method, including ConnectAsync and CloseAsync. Whereas with TimeoutAfter you have two separated, local timeouts one for each operations. So, the two solutions are not the same.

Comment: Do you want me to leave a post to show you how can you fix it by defining "local" timeout policies?

Comment: @PeterCsala, yes, please. You can type it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TimeoutAfter` extension method is applied twice, separately for the `ConnectAsync` and for the `CloseAsync` methods. It means that each method call has a "local" timeout.

In your Polly version you have defined a "global" / "overarching" timeout which includes everything from `ConnectAsync` till `CloseAsync`.

So, the two versions are **not** identical.

BTW your code have some problems:

- `TimeoutAsync` can't have a `Handle` clause
- `retryPolicy` is not defined in this scope

---

You can replace your `TimeoutAfter` code to this to utilize Polly:

```
public static async Task TimeoutAfter(Func<CancellationToken, Task> task, CancellationToken token, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    try
    {
        await CreateTimeoutConstraint(timeout)
            .ExecuteAsync(async (ct) => await task(ct), token)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (TimeoutRejectedException ex)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException($"Task timed out after {timeout}", ex);
    }
}

private static IAsyncPolicy CreateTimeoutConstraint(TimeSpan threshold)
    => Policy.TimeoutAsync(threshold, TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic,
    (context, timeSpan, task, ex) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Task timed out after {timeSpan.TotalSeconds} seconds");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
```

- In order to respect both the user cancellation token and timeout cancellation token you have to change the signature

  - The method should receive a function which anticipates a `CancellationToken` and returns a `Task`
  - It should also receive the user cancellation token
- In the `ExecuteAsync` call you "combine" the `TimeoutPolicy` and the user cancellation token

  - If the `token` asks for cancellation first then `ExecuteAsync` will throw a `TaskCanceledException`
  - If TimeoutPolicy asks for cancellation first then `ExecuteAsync` will throw a `TimeoutRejectedException` which is translated to an `OperationCanceledException`

The usage of this method looks like this:

```
await TimeoutAfter((token) => _webSocket.ConnectAsync(_uri, token), ct, OpenTimeoutMs);

...

await TimeoutAfter((token) => _webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", token), ct, CloseTimeoutMs);
```